# Why does potential and force at an exterior point change on considering discrete masses at centre of mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, mass

Why does this happen? Why can’t the centre of mass of a system produce the same effect as a system of discrete or continuous mass? Similar thing was observed by me in case of charges

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going wrong with your very first equation, the sum of potential energy between two masses is proportional to the sum of the masses.$$E=\frac{G(m1+m2)}b-\frac{G(m1+m2)}a$$
Assuming bodies fall towards each other from a to b.

This causes a sum change of velocity of the two body's towards each other.$$E=\frac{1}2v^2-\frac{1}2u^2$$Where u does not matter if it is the sum of velocities already accumulated from the two bodies interacting or if it is the velocity one body is thrown towards the other.
Assuming you know the masses you can then pick apart the sum velocity to get the velocities of the individual bodies. The masses being inversely proportion to the velocities and as we are talking the same period of time; inversely proportional to the distances each mass moves in respect to the common centre. Ditto for the rate of change in velocities.$$v1=v\frac{m2}{m1+m2}$$$$v2=v\frac{m1}{m1+m2}$$$$s1=(a-b)\frac{m2}{m1+m2}$$$$a1=a\frac{v1}{v1+v2}$$
Etc.